# How to do multiple redirections with multiple permissions in angularjs using angular permission library?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-permission, angularjs-1.7

I want to have a route that has multiple permissions, and it can only be accessible if all of them are met and I want a different redirection rule for each of them, somewhat like below:

```
{
    only: ['loggedin', 'hasProject'],
    redirectTo: {
        loggedin: {
            state: 'login'
        },
        hasProject: {
            state: 'createProject'
        }
    }
}
```

I checked doc of [angular-permission](https://github.com/RafaelVidaurre/angular-permission/wiki/Usage-in-ui-router-states#multiple-redirection-rules), and it has mentioned that `only` option works like `OR`.

> Between values in array operator OR is used to create an alternative. If
>   you need AND operator between permissions define additional PermRole
>   containing set of those.

How can I make it work as `AND`?